# Can't seem to uninstall the JetBrains Toolbox

Tags: windows, jetbrains-toolbox

When I'm trying to remove the app from the "apps and components" setting in Windows 10 Home 1803 I get an error message similar like this: Can't find file C:\Users\Laptop-User\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\bin\Uninstall.exe
This is true, because there really isn't a file named Uninstall.exe in that folder. Though there is a file named: Uninstall.exe.nsis, but if I change the name of how it should run in this case: .exe.nsis to just .exe I get further, but still not the result I want which is uninstalling this app. This time when I try to uninstall it I get an Administrator box where I need to confirm followed by the same error message as before.

I can't seem to find the solution for this and I hope someone has found one, because this is a well known problem to other users as well I've read.

Comment: The problem mentioned is faced quite frequently, [this](https://toolbox-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001313270-How-to-uninstall-Toolbox-App-) thread might help.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem: I could not find it on "Apps and components" to uninstall it.

What I ended up doing was stopping it from running at login, then deleted its folder.

[image: Here is where you stop it from running at login:]

After that, reboot or log out and log in again, and you shouldn't see it on the taskbar anymore.

To delete its folder, press the Windows Key + R to get the "Run" menu, then type `%localappdata%` and hit OK. That should take you to `C:\Users\[your username]\AppData\Local`. You should see a folder called `Jetbrains`. Go into it and delete the Toolbox folder.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help me one single bit